# Does meaning change in phrase below?

Tags: meaning

1) Book’s chapter for children

If I say;

2) Chapter for children of book.

Second phrase sounds like “Children belongs to book” . I know it is very absurd. But I just wonder if the correct use is only first phrase? Or would it be understood the same if I say second one? I mean in second phrases I want to say

(Chapter for children) (of book) = (chapter of for children) belongs to book or

What you would understand be (Chapter for)  (children of book) If I say the second phrase  .

I mean ; Is  Book’s chapter for children  the same as  Chapter for children of book?

Answer (score 1):

Neither phrase seems clear or idiomatic. In the second phrase you have the order of the prepositional phrases wrong.

> A chapter of a book for children.

Even so, there is ambiguity, since it is unusual to have just one chapter of a book which is for children. Usually the whole book is for children, and that is how I would interpret that phrase.

As this is an unusual situation you need to be more explicit.

> Although this is an adult book, one chapter of this book was written for child readers. This chapter ...

Comment: As you say for example this book is about health. But there are some chapters for children. This is why A chapter of book for children means that  chapter of book that is for children . I don't want to say book is for children , I want to say chapter for children.

Comment: Yes, noted.  This is an less common situation, so your readers will need it described explictly.

Comment: You mean; both meaning can be understood . This is why I need to give more information. Chapter for children of book mean : Chapter which is for children and belongs to book and chapther for children who belongs book.( even if it seems absurd and weird ) I  just wanted to learn ıf there are two meaning or not without  caring whether it is idomatic .

Comment: We wouldn't say "of book". "The chapter for children of (or in) the book _Health for everyone_..." (or whatever it may be called).

Comment: Sorry . I couldn't understand  "The chapter for children of (or in) the book Health for everyone..."

Comment: I still think that there are two manings that ı said above. even if one s idomatic

Comment: Yes, the phrase "A chapter of a book for children" is ambiguous. So without further context the more common meaning is likely to be taken.  Since you want to express a different meaning, you need to give more information.

Comment: Actually I asked If the phrase” Chapter for children of book” has two meanings or not like ; Chapter which is for children and belongs to book and chapther for children who belongs book and as second meaning book has chapter which is for children.